# calculate weighted s.d in r

Tags: r, standards, weighted, deviation

I want to calculate in r  weighted mean and weighted standard deviation (the weights are sample weights, for a survey sample. It is suppose to show how many units in the population represent each unit in the sample).

I tried to calculate this by two ways and got the same answers for the means, but different answers for the s.d.

Is one of the ways correct?

the first way-

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b_gender<-c('men','men','women')
c_weight<-c(1,1,2)
table1<-tableby(gender~a, weights=c_wei)
```

another way-

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
gender<-c('men','men','women')
c_weight<-c(1,1,2)
w.mean(a, c_wei)
   w.ds(a, c_wei)
```

Comment: for the first way I used arsenal package, for the second way I used Weighted.Desc.Stat.

Comment: I assume the funciton used is `w.sd` instead of `w.ds`?.  In the documentation, it says the function defined is `function(x, mu)  ( (sum(mu*x*x)/sum(mu)) - w.mean(x,mu)^2 )^`.